# How to close a modal when leaving the current page in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am beginner with ionic and i am currently stuck on a modal closure.
My problem is that when a modal is open and we go back to the previous page, the modal remains open.
So i'm trying to close a modal when we leave the current page.

For example:

```
addTask(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(PostSettingsCrudPage,  {
idpost: this.post.id});
    modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.RefreshTasks();
    });
    profileModal.present();
  }
```

I found an example that proposes to use the viewController:

```
viewController.dismiss()
```

I tried using it in the ionViewDidLeave method but I get the following error

```
Runtime error : removeView was not found
```

I found a temporary solution (add the instance of the modal in a variable of the component to recover it when we leave the page and call the dismiss method) but this solution does not suit me.
Will anyone have an idea please?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/close-modal-with-button/66566/4 check this out

Comment: Your temporary solution seems correct. Why does it not suit you ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
Yes there is this solution, but if the user does not click the button and return to the previous page, there will be the same problem. I would like the modal to close itself when we leave the page

Comment: This solution does not suit me because I can have several differents modals on my page. So I have to store the instance of each modal. I think there is a better way but I do not find which one